# Building expression related to Attribute Rules using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: fields-attributes, arcgis-pro

Referencing [Creating Attribute Rules using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345548/arcgis-pro-attribute-rules)

Now I am trying to build an expression. First it does not give me the option to choose the type of syntax in the expression builder GUI. (ie. Arcade, Python or SQL)

[image]

Secondly I used this script

```
var FID = $tSignalPoles.FID;
if(FID == 0001)
  return "SP-" + NextSequenceValue("tSignalPoles")
```

But it cannot find feature that I am calling out in the line 1 variable even though that is the correct source name in the database.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isempty($feature.FID)) //If the field is empty or has the default value
return concatenate("SP-" + nextsequencevalue("Traffic_SignalPole_ID")); //calculate a 
new id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var FID = $tSignalPoles.FID;
if(FID == 0001)
  return "SP-" + NextSequenceValue("tSignalPoles")
```

`$tSingalPoles.FID;` should be changed to `$feature.FID;`

Comment: The expression is valid, but when I go to create new features, a new FID is not created, the field value remains nulls.